# no communication with the instrument (no answer) Minimalmodbus

Tags: python, pyserial, modbus, minimalmodbus

I'm having problem with minimalmodbus library. The slave does not respond to the master's request, I want to request a read. I'm using the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, with Python 3.10.1, it's the minimalmodbus library with version 2.0. I'm using the Arduino Mega as a slave and I'm also using a Mini Adapter Serial Converter USB to RS485 is a Converter Module RS485 for Arduino.

```
import serial
import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM6',1)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.serial.timeout = 10
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
instrument.debug = True
temperature = instrument.read_register(1,1)
print(temperature)
```

```
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): 01 03 00 01 00 01 D5 CA (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM6
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 87898406.00 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument:  (0 bytes), roundtrip time:10.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 0 ms.
```

Comment: What OS are your running on the Pi? (`COM6` looks like a windows serial port, on linux I'd expect something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`). There are many potential causes here (e.g. issue with the Arduino software, wiring, incorrect baud rate/parity etc) so more information will be needed. I'd suggest starting with a known good app on the Pi (e.g. [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)/[[modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)) and verifying that you can poll the device before writing your own code.

Comment: the operating system used is Raspbian. I changed the port and checked the wiring. Everything is fine with the settings.

Comment: Without more information (and the exact code you are using) its not really possible to help. You will need to go through things step by step; perhaps start by looking at logs from the Arduino to see if it is receiving anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue on Win10 python 3.7.9. When I write

```
import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 2)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True

reg_0 = instrument.read_register(0, 0)
reg_1 = instrument.read_register(1, 0)

print(reg_0)
print(reg_1)

instrument.serial.close()
```

I have error message "minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)". But, when I write

```
import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 2)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
instrument.debug = True

reg_0 = instrument.read_register(0, 0)
reg_1 = instrument.read_register(1, 0)

print(reg_0)
print(reg_1)

instrument.serial.close()
```

all works correct.
I use Arduino UNO as a slave. In ModbusPoll both registrers read correct

Upd. When I use construction "try... except..." all works correctly

```
import minimalmodbus

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 2)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True

try:
    reg_0 = instrument.read_register(0, 0)
except minimalmodbus.NoResponseError:
    reg_0 = instrument.read_register(0, 0)      
reg_1 = instrument.read_register(1, 0)

print(reg_0)
print(reg_1)

instrument.serial.close()
```